# Mongoose join two different collections with different foreign key

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Users Schema:

```js
{
  username: "milkeypony",
  _id: "_mongodbID",
  id: "random_30_characters_string"
  ...
}
```

Blog Schema

```js
{
  title: "_title",
  _id: "_mongodbID",
  author: "random_30_characters_string"
  ...
}
```

The `Blogs.author` is the same ID as with in `Users.id`

And what I'm trying to do is when I use `Blogs.findOne()` to fetch some blog post, Mongoose will also help me fetch some user data.

And I already successfully done this with raw Mongo shell command

```js
db.blogs.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "author",
      foreignField: "id",
      as: "author"
    }
  }
])
```

And I try the mongoose `populate` method, but it didn't work out for me

Comment: I believe I did that at the top of the question

Answer (score 5):

make sure Blogs schema like have

```
author:{
  type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,   
  ref: 'Users'
}
```

and populate like below

```
Blogs.findAll({})
.populate({
  path:author
})
.exec((err, blogs)=>{
  console.log(err,blogs);
}))
```

more info check offical doc