# Mongoose Foregin Key mapping

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, nodes

I'm new to MongoDB/Mongoose and trying to figure out how to map relationships between Schema. I don't think issue is with .populate(). At creation of new user and clients, I do not see the relationship reflected in collection

User (login via local/social) has many Clients.
A set of Clients belong to 1 User

1. Is this the correct way to declare foreign key? {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Client'}
2. Should both Schema have the each other's foreign key to relate to one another?
3. Is there any additional code required when creating User/Client in order for the data from foreign key to show up? I read something about populate()

User

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var userSchema = new Schema({

local: {
    id: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    name: String,
    mobile: String,
    clients: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Client'}

},

google: {
    id: String,
    token: String,
    email: String,
    name: String,
    clients: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Client'}

}

});
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Client

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var clientSchema = new Schema({

    id: String,
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    mobile: String,
    user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Client', clientSchema);
```

Create User

```
app.post("/api/user", function (req, res) {
const user = req.body;
console.log(user);

User.findOne({ 'local.email': user.email },
  function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      handleError(err, res);
      return;
    }
    if (result) {
      res.status(500).send("Email already exists in database");
    } else {
      var newUser = new User();
      newUser.local.password = generateHash(user.password);
      newUser.local.email = user.email;
      newUser.local.name = user.name;
      newUser.local.mobile = user.mobile;
      newUser.save(function (err, result) {
        res.status(201).send("User added to database");
      });
    }

  });
 });
```

Create Client

```
app.post("/api/client", function (req, res) {
const client = req.body;
console.log(client);

Client.findOne({
  $and: [
         { firstname: client.firstname },
         { lastname: client.lastname }
       ]
},
  function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      handleError(err, res);
      return;
    }
    if (result) {
      res.status(500).send({msg:"Client already exists in database"});
    } else {
      var newClient = new Client();
      newClient.firstname = client.firstname;
      newClient.lastname = client.lastname;
      newClient.mobile = client.mobile;
      newClient.save(function (err, result) {
        res.status(201).send("Client added to database");
      });
    }

  });

 });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose join two different collections with different foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47486583/mongoose-join-two-different-collections-with-different-foreign-key)

Comment: thanks @shivshankar. I've seen that question and I've more questions but because I've not collected enough credits on stackoverflow, I can't add comments to ask more question. For mine, at the creation stage, the user collection does not have client data so my issue is not .populate() I think...

Comment: ok take some credit from me

Comment: Thank you @@shivshankar! I just tried it looks like I need reputation of 50. Ugh not there yet. Anyway the question is on **find** data but my question is on **save** data, it's different